# Am I parallelizing this file transfer correctly?

Tags: python, ubuntu, multiprocessing, file-transfer

I have a lot of "small" files that I want to copy from one server (mounted with sshfs) into my local machine.

Using `stfp get` or `ssh, cp` only transfers one file at a time, so I has a huge overhead and it takes forever.

I wanted to start multiple copying processes simultaneously to try to speed things up. I was not able to do this with bash, so this was my attempt on Python, using multiprocessing to start 30 parallel, non-overlapping, copying processes:

```
import multiprocessing        
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool   
import os
import shutil

def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False, ignore=None):
    if not os.path.exists(dst):
        os.makedirs(dst)
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)

        if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)



list_of_folders = os.listdir('source/of/folders')          


# PARALLELIZATION INTO 30 PROCESSES:

pool = Pool(30)
pool.map(copytree, list_of_folders, chunksize=250)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

However this seems to be just as slow as the copying in sequence. Checking on htop most processors dont seem active, and the file transfer in total is around 10MB/Second...

Why is this not working as expected? How can this be achieved?

Comment: `scp -r` will help you. Another option is to tar on the server, copy and untar

Comment: @Marat I agree that compressing the source files will remove all the overhead for each single small file, although the compression itself might take way too long as well (its about 4 TB of hundreds of thousands of files). I was using `scp -r` before, which was a sequential copy and therefore very slow, am I missing something?

Comment: well, multithreading won't make it faster, and 4Tb over scp with enabled compression doesn't sound like a terrible amount

Comment: Note also that you don't have to use compression with tar, you can just use it to turn lots of small files into a single large one.

Comment: @Marat why won't multi-threading make it faster?

Comment: Try rsync (read through the man page for options) Copying between machines in not usually limited by CPU, but rather by bandwidth. Rsync creators took many circumstances into account, so it can automatically compress/decompress, resume and do other stuff with very little effort from the user. I think it would be better to use rsync directly to the host instead of rsync <source> <mounted dir>

Comment: @hirschme because there are two possible bottlenecks here (reading small files and network bandwidth) and multithreading won't eliminate any of them.

Comment: @Marat tried making a big zip file out of the folder and the compression was even slower than the transfer.. sadly in this case not an efficient option. Unless I find some compression method that works faster.

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow similar behavior with `rsync` directly from the unmounted server. Speeds around 10MB/s, just as slow as the other methods

Comment: @hirschme, what is your bandwidth on both ends? Maybe it just can't go any faster?

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow how would you report the bandwith on both ends? Speed is about 10MB/sec, fluctuating between 0 and 60. So bandwith has to be at least 60MB/s right? Tools like `ethtool`, `bmon` and `nload` all report same speeds. `dmesg enp0s3` (name of my network interface) shows "NIC link is up to 1000 Mbs"

Comment: Seems like you know how to benchmark your network. It may be that you just have a slow-ish internet connection (with rhese speeds I am assuming the 2 machines are not in the same LAN). Or that parts of the network in between are of low quality (slow switches, and stuff we have no control over). My last attempt would be tar/gzip with low compression level for speed and then rsync that file.